# Can we use web SQL local database with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, cordova, web-sql

I'm creating an offline application using web SQL local database with JavaScript.

When internet will not connected on that time all the entries will be inserted in local database web SQL.

But when I am connected to the internet then web SQL local database will synchronize with the live database and new entries of local database which is not available in live database will be inserted automatically.

Later on this application will be deployed in Phonegap.

Here is code for local database (SQL transactions)

Open database:

```
var db = openDatabase('retaurant', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
```

New table And insert data to the table:

```
var username = "Test";
var password = "test";
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , username,password)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO user (username,password) VALUES ("'+username+'","'+password+'")');
});
```

Delete entry from database

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
     tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM user WHERE id=?", [id],
     function (tx, results) {    });
});
```

This code is for local, now how can I sync this database with live database using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access local DB from PHP, you can use javascript only.

I think you storage total item in local DB, or last_id of all item in local DB.

On page loaded, using ajax to compare total of local DB and Live DB. Then load new item from Live DB and insert to local DB. OR clear all local DB and load all item from Live DB.

Hope help you!

Comment: This can be done by simply ajax and php and javascript right ?

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents: Firstly, WebSQL API is deprecated then why did you consider using the same? Better use some adapter like [LocalForage](https://mozilla.github.io/localForage/), [YdnDB](https://github.com/yathit/ydndb-demo), [LawnChair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) etc. which will hide the underlying database API (WebSQL or IndexedDB).
IndexedDB specification has replaced WebSQL.